# How to SED these paragraphs to MCQ format?

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl

My data:

```
Question Nr.  311
Main proteins are in the lorem ipsun
A Lorem RNA test
B Cells
C Metoclom
D Cells
E Muscles

Question Nr.  312
Main proteins are in the lorem ipsun
A Lorem
B Cells
C Metoclom
D Cells
E Muscles

...
```

Wanted format:

```
\item 
Main proteins are in the lorem ipsun

A Lorem RNA test

B Cells

C Metoclom

D Cells

E Muscles

\item
Main proteins are in the lorem ipsun

A Lorem

B Cells

C Metoclom

D Cells

E Muscles

\item ...
```

Where I am planning to present the options each on new line.

My attempt:

```
sed s/Question Nr.*/\item/g
```

Which should replace all lines having *Question Nr[anything on the line]*
- problem is in the detection what comes after, since there can be many options, but the end of options is `\n\n` i.e. the newline.

Semistage problem here:

```
\item 
Main proteins are in the lorem ipsun
A Lorem RNA test
B Cells
C Metoclom
D Cells  
E Muscles

\item 
Main proteins are in the lorem ipsun
A Lorem
B Cells
C Metoclom
D Cells  
E Muscles
```

Other challenges

- Have capitalized words like *HIV* and *RNA* in the options; some solutions below insert empty line after *HI* and *RN*

---

How can you get my wanted output by `sed`/`perl`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way with `tr`+`sed`:

```
tr -s \\n <infile | sed '$!G;s/Question Nr.*/\\item/'
```

`tr` squeezes all newlines and then `sed` appends hold space content (empty newline) to each line except the last one, replacing `Question Nr.*` with `\item`.  With this method you won't be able to edit the file in-place. I chose `tr` here as it's faster then `sed`'s regex (even if it's not as clean as a `sed`-only solution)

Comment: Very nice. Add an empty line check at the beginning of the `sed` command like so (untested): `/^$/d;`  Or if you like, use `/^[[:space:]]*$/d;` to catch whitespace only lines.  This gives `sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d;/Question Nr.*/!G;s//\\item/'` as probably the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 6):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^Question Nr\..*/\\item/; s/^\([A-Z] .*\)/\n\1/' file
```

- The first `s///` replaces `Question Nr.` with `\item` similar to the `sed` command in your question.
- The second one replaces line that start with a capital letter from `A` to `Z`, but only one followed by a space. This whole line is replaced with itself `\1` repending a newline `\n`.

---

The output:

```
\item
Main proteins are in the lorem ipsun

A Lorem

B Cells

C Metoclom

D Cells

E Muscles

\item
Main proteins are in the lorem ipsun

A Lorem

B Cells

C Metoclom

D Cells

E Muscles
```

Answer (score 5):

If it doesn't need to be `sed`, Perl's "paragraph mode" is perfect for this. From `man perlrun`:

```
   -0[octal/hexadecimal]
        specifies the input record separator ($/) as an octal or
        hexadecimal number.  [...]

        The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph
        mode.  [...]
```

So, using `-00` tells perl to define "lines" as paragraphs, it uses `\n\n` as the end of line character. With that in mind, you could do something like:

```
$ perl -00pe 's/Question.*/\\item/; s/[A-Z] /\n$&/g;' file
\item
Main proteins are in the lorem ipsun

A Lorem

B Cells

C Metoclom

D Cells

E Muscles

\item
Main proteins are in the lorem ipsun

A Lorem

B Cells

C Metoclom

D Cells

E Muscles
```

The first substitution operator replaces any lines matching the string `Question` with `\item` and the second adds a newline before each capital letter followed by a space.

Comment: Again only 1 second diference =)

Comment: @chaos indeed :) But yours was cleverer so I copied it. It is much simpler to replace `Question` with `\item` than to do it in two steps as I was doing. Thanks!

Comment: There are some problems when the data contains words like "HIV" in the body. I am trying to second match to start at the beginning of the line by `s/^[A-Z] /` unsuccessfully. Why `s/^` does not work here as expected?

Comment: Unsuccessful attempt also `s/^\([A-Z] \)/`

Comment: @Masi because the "line" is now a paragraph so `^` matches the beginning of the paragraph. You'll have to use `s/\n[A-Z] //` instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -e'/./!d;$!G;/^Q/c\' -e'\\item' <in >out
```

That will `d`elete every blank line in input, `G`et a blank line out of hold space and append it to all non-blank lines which are `!` not the `$` last, and `c`hange any pattern space `^`beginning with the character *`Q`* to the one-line fixed-string *`\item`* on output.

When run on your example input, the output is:

```
\item
Main proteins are in the lorem ipsun

A Lorem

B Cells

C Metoclom

D Cells

E Muscles

\item
Main proteins are in the lorem ipsun

A Lorem

B Cells

C Metoclom

D Cells

E Muscles
```

*(with no trailing blank line at the tail of output)*

Portably the `sed` `-e`xpression statement should not end in a backslash like that, and so it might be written:

```
sed -e'/./!d;$!G;/^Q/c\'"$(printf '\n\\\item')" <in >out
```

Answer (score 4):

Now with `awk`:

```
awk '$1 ~ /[ABCDEM]/ {print $0"\n"} $1 ~ /Question/ {print "\\item"}' inputfile
```

If the line starts with A, B, C, D, E or M (for Main), it prints that line and an extra `\n`. If the line starts with "Question", it simply prints `\item`.

Comment: Pretty sure "Main proteins" was an example.  I don't think this check is sufficient for the OP's actual input.

Comment: I thought that also, but it is quite easy to adapt.

Comment: i agree. i consider that if you can demonstrate how a command works and how it might be modified to taste, then you've written a pretty good answer.