# To Apply Answers to MCQs

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl

I am now extending my own answers to MCQs, as made [How to SED these paragraphs to MCQ format?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244496/16920).

Data in file.txt

```
1   c
2   a
```

Data in exam.tex

```
\item
Which of the following lorem ipsun are the best playstation games you have played? 

A Pattman

B Pokemon

C Lorem

D Ipsun

E Heillui

\item
Which of the following lorem ipsun are the best playstation games you have played? 

A Pattman

B Pokemon

C Lorem

D Ipsun

E Heillui
```

Wanted output where bold made by the answers in the *file.txt*

```
\item
Which of the following lorem ipsun are the best playstation games you have played? 

A Pattman

B Pokemon

\textbf{C Lorem}

D Ipsun

E Heillui

\item
Which of the following lorem ipsun are the best playstation games you have played? 

\textbf{A Pattman}

B Pokemon

C Lorem

D Ipsun

E Heillui
```

### Pseudocode

- for loop \item's in Perl paragraph mode

  - for loop empty lines in each paragaph by the count in the list (a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5)

    - apply \textbf to the beginning of the line; and } to the end of the line
  - step out of the current paragraph
- end

Pseudocode with Python-Perl

```
for item in items 

   perl -00pe 's/\\item\n.*\n{$item}^/\textbf{/;' file
   perl -00pe 's/\\item\n.*\n{$item}$/}/;' file

end
```

where I do not like that I handle the beginning and the end in separate commands.

---

How can you apply answer to MCQs by Perl/SED/Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{   printf '[13*%d-n[bs]pc]s%c\n' 9 a 7 b 5 c 3 d 1 e
    tr  -s ' \n' lx <file.txt; }  |  dc |
sed -f- -eb -e:s -e's/.*/\\textbf{&}/' exam.txt
```

That uses the `dc` reverse-polish-notation calculator to generate a `sed` script that looks like:

```
8bs
17bs
```

...which is then concatenated with the `sed` scripts entered on the command-line and so results in every line number which is *not* included in the generated script to be `b`ranched away, and for the those that *are* included to have the string `\textbf{` inserted before whatever exists on the line and `}` appended to its tail.

It will work for more than just the two sections, of course. Basically it multiplies the leading number on each line in *`file.txt`* by 13 and then subtracts from the product 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 for either of e, d, c, b, a respectively to arrive at the list of targeted line numbers.

In any case, all `sed` has to do at the end is the default print it does for every line which it doesn't edit before branching away, or else to do the one substitution for your string. `tr` and `dc` are both *very* fast utilities, and they handle nearly all of the pre-processing.

---

Possible advantages to this approach:

- No comparisons need be made between the two files.
- No regular expression matching is required at all.

  - While true, `sed`'s processing might benefit slightly from an initial additional filter to prevent it attempting to match *every* line number against those in the list, like:

    ```sh
    ... | sed -e'/^[ABCDE] /!b' -f- ...
    ```
- The answers in *file.txt* need not be in any particular order or even completely represent every question in *exam.txt*.

Possible disadvantages:

- Each answer letter in *file.txt* must be lowercase.

  - use `tr -s '[:upper:] \n' \[:lower:]lx` to handle either/or.
- At least one intermediate space and intervening newline is required between the answer number and the answer letter and between each answer respectively in *file.txt*, though any larger number is permitted with the exception that no leading blank-lines can be found before the first answer, and no line can begin or end with spaces.
- Every question/answer block in *exam.txt* must be comprised of exactly 13 lines *(excepting the last, which need not include a trailing blank-line)*.

---

This depends on one or two GNU `dc` extensions as written. Here is a more portable version:

```
{   printf '[13*%d-p[s]pc]s%c\n' 9 a 7 b 5 c 3 d 1 e
    tr  -s ' \n' lx <file.txt;}| dc | paste -db - -|
sed -f- -eb -e:s -e's/.*/\\textbf{&}/' exam.txt
```

...either way you write it, though:

---

```
\item
Which of the following lorem ipsun are the best playstation games you have played?

A Pattman

B Pokemon

\textbf{C Lorem}

D Ipsun

E Heillui

\item
Which of the following lorem ipsun are the best playstation games you have played?

\textbf{A Pattman}

B Pokemon

C Lorem

D Ipsun

E Heillui
```